# Building/Running a Streaming Weka Text Classifer in Java

Tags: java, nlp, machine-learning, classification, weka

We have been using the Weka Explorer GUI to build a few classifier models. Now Testing is complete we would like to implement this model within a Java application so it can take new messages.

So for new messages we need to tokenize the message, match up tokens in the message with tokens used to build the word vector for the model and then parse this word vector to the model.

How should we go about this process? Are there any examples available?

How do we deal with new tokens (i.e. words that appear in new text messages which are not a part of the word vector used to build the model)?

For the classifier preprocessing/tokenising we are using the NGram Tokenizer, Stemmer and IDF Transform. So we need to figure out how to do these steps before we can create a new instancebased on the text we would like to classify.

As a side When building a classifier in the explorer, under more options there is a button to choose 'output classifier code' which sounds like it outputs Java source code to build and use the model however this option is disabled. Tested with a number of different classifiers (RF, NB) and it doesnt change. I'm guessing its not implemented for these?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my best knowledge you need to retrain weka classifier when a new training sample arrives. I am not aware of an online classification algorithm in Wekka.

ps. Weka is Java based, so you can use its libs in your application. Here is a good example: http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code.

Comment: Thanks. I know that there is no way to add new training samples without retraining (though some classifier models are updatable). However classifying new messages, which are untagged (i.e. a test set without tags). For the classifier we are using the NGram Tokenizer, Stemmer and IDF Transform. So we need to figure out how to do these steps before we can create a new instancebased on the text we would like to classify.

Comment: It is not very clear for me, what your problem is. As I understand you have a text processing pipeline in place for processing new messages. You know how wekka works and you can embedded it in your java application. So now, you are looking for a way to handle unforeseeable tokens in new messages. Do I understand it correctly?